# about standard directory layout of maven project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

Please help me to get rid of this problem, I have copied a pom.xml file from seleniumhq.org website for setting up Selenium-Webdriver-Project for Java, the the pom.xml file ::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                        <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                                <version>2.45.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                </project>
```

When running the command on the project folder path:

```
mvn clean install
```

and for Importing  Project into Eclipse using Maven

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

the standard directory layout  is not getting created i.e.

- src/main/java
- src/main/resource
- src/test/java
- src/test/resource

or to be precise the `src/main` and `src/test` folders are not getting created like when I create a maven project from Eclipse IDE.

What is the reason behind this kind of difference in directory structure creation

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Integration_with_Other_Tools.pdf)

pom.xml will also be created automatically. Afterwards you'll have to add required dependencies in it.

Comment: Well, the steps you have tried to show me, is actually done earlier by me, and that is why it created the questions of why this kind of directory layout differences is created when I am creating it through commands and through IDE...

Answer (score 0):

Copying a pom file and running install won't create you the relevant folders. In order to generate a new project consider using the [archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) plugin.

In your case you will need to manually create the folders and maven will simply use them in both install and eclipse plugins.

Comment: Well I tried the same way I did earlier but this time with a trick after completing the steps, I have removed the jre-1.5 error which was shown, and replace it with  the system jre1.8.0, this time I got the src/main/java & src/test/java folder... but not the src/main/resources nor the src/java/resources... Is there any other way the pom.xml file could be changed to add those missed two